# css on ipad sometimes not how it should be

Tags: css, ipad, safari

Sometimes I open my page the iPad doenst show it right. Mostly it is when I reload the page. the problem also is in the safari. I've created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PkCPR/) to show you how I have done it.

```
<a href="#">         
  <div class="item">                
    <div class="text">Text1</div>         
    <div class="text2"><b>Text2</b></div>         
    <img class="logo" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x50/09f/fff.png" alt="logo"width="100">  
    <div class="balken2">Text3</div>
  </div>
</a>
```

In Firefox its all right, the Text3 Bar is at the end and the other 2 are centered after the image which is dynamic and not everytime the same size as you see.on ipad it shows it sometimes like this http://www.imagebanana.com/view/ynvggcu8/ipad.jpg. How can i fix this? Thanks for your help!

Comment: are you sure you have internet connection on your Ipad? meaning is you wifi connection stable? looks like Ipad lost connection and the images are not loaded.

Comment: the picture was from safari. i have internet connection, the text 3 bars are also not right. I want them to be everytime at the end :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/parkerwyoung/PkCPR/9/

Put this on `.item`

```
position: relative;
```

Put this on `.balken2`

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
width: 150px;
padding-right: 0;
padding-left: 0;
```

The problem is when the image doesn't load, the `.balken2` class has nothing to guide off of in the layout. This code positions it so it doesn't have to rely on the image being there. Hope this helps!

Comment: if i build it in my version i get it at the end of the "items" div :(

Comment: Did you take a look at my fiddle link in the comment? I removed the image to simulate your problem on the iPad when the images didn't load, you would need to replace that image on your version to make it work properly.